# Understanding the proof of the existence of Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic as explained on wikipedea.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading this [wikipedea article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic#Existence):

> We need to show that every integer greater than $1$ is a product of primes. By induction: assume it is true for all numbers between $1$ and $n$. If $n$ is prime, there is nothing more to prove (a prime is a trivial product of primes, a "product" with only one factor). Otherwise, there are integers $a$ and $b$, where $n = ab$ and $1 < a ≤ b < n$. By the induction hypothesis, $a = p_1p_2...p_j$ and $b = q_1q_2...q_k$ are products of primes. But then $n = ab = p_1p_2...p_ jq_1q_2...q_k$ is a product of primes.

They said, *"If n is prime, there is nothing more to prove..."*. Haven't we have to show that $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$? Even in the second case where $n$ is not supposed to be prime they do not show that FTA exists for the $n+1$th number. Why is that?

My understanding:

There are two cases, either $n+1$ is prime or it is not. If it is prime then it's fine. If it is not prime then then we must have $n+1=a_1a_2....a_p$ s.t. $a_i<n$ but every number less than $n$ can be factorized in primes so $n+1$ can also be.

Comment: That proof proceeds by _strong induction_.

Comment: To add to Zircht's comment. This means we assume it is true for all $k<n$ and prove that it is true for $n$. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction).

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of this kind of _Induction_.

Comment: When it says "assume it is true for all numbers between $1$ and $n$", it means *strictly* between $1$ and $n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Then it is no-different-from(or quite similar to) the usual induction. They assumed $P(1)$ to $P(n-1)$ are true and then they have shown it true for $P(n)$. And $P(n)$ is true because $P(n-k)$ is--which is presumed to be true-- k varies from n-1 to 1.

Comment: You can use "usual induction" to prove that "strong induction" is a valid method of argument. They are logically equivalent, but sometimes strong induction is a more convenient way to do things.